# Error executing: java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M

Tags: java, memory-leaks

```
$ java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M
```

While running the above command I got the error below. Please help me how to set JVM Heap memory in AIX box. Here I'm using java 5.

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)    or  java -jar [-options] jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -cp -classpath <directories and zip/jar files separated by :>
              set search path for application classes and resources
    -D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
    -version  print product version
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -? -help  print this help message
    -X        print help on non-standard options
```

Answer (score 12):

Well, you have to execute SOME java program, not just the JVM. The options itself are fine. Try `java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -cp somejar.jar mystuff.Main` or something.

Answer (score 0):

What about export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M" (unix) or set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M (windows)?

Comment: That probably won't help.  The `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable is not used by the `java` command.

Comment: Thanks for response. i have added in script and working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try This also :

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -classpath jar1.jar:jar2.jar packageName.YourMainClassName Arguments
```